# How can I share my organization Google doc "anyone with link"?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

I've created documents using my business g-docs (I'm a freelancer). When I try to set the document "anyone with the link can view|comment|edit" I am only given options "anyone IN YOUR ORGANIZATION with the link can..."

Is there a more advanced per-document setting I can use to make a truly public document from my organization, or do I need to change org-level settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to adjust your domain level setting under [Drive and Docs > Sharing settings](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?hl=en#AppDetails:service=Drive%20and%20Docs&flyout=sharing)